# Error while running python in apache httpd

Tags: python, linux, apache, web, pexpect

> "Error! pty.fork() failed: out of pty devices name 'child' is not
>   defined name"

How do I resolve the above error ? This is seen while spawning ssh using pexpect from apache webserver?

Comment: Running via webserver using cgi. Yes WSGI
Does anybody have solution ?

Comment: It's most likely a selinux problem. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954285/apache-pty-errors-in-cgi-perl-file-while-creating-a-new-expect-object